# RE to handle both formats

Tags: python, regex

I have two type of files.

One contains the line as below:

```
"55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async"
```

Another contains the line as blow:

```
>55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async</a></span><br></td>
```

In both cases, I'd like to get the content starting with `LongUrl` and ending with `</a>` or the end of line.

```
>>> b="55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async"
>>> a=">55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async</a></span><br></td>"
>>> re.findall(r'LongUrl\d*.\d*s:[^<]+',a)
['LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async']
>>> re.findall(r'LongUrl\d*.\d*.*$',b)
['LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async']
```

Can you help with a single RE that can cover both?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just `LongUrl\d+[^<]+`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = ">55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async</a></span><br></td>"
>>> b = "55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async"
>>> re.findall(r'LongUrl\d+[^<]+', a)
['LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async']
>>> re.findall(r'LongUrl\d+[^<]+', b)
['LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async']
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I need to check to ensure there is number after longUrl string, and ignore those occurrences that don't have digits after the string

Comment: @user2716941 Then tell us that in your question! **Especially** when dealing with things like regexes, it is critical that you provide *all* the requirements. If that's your only additional requirement, this is an easy modification: just make the regex in the above answer `r'LongUrl\d+[^<]*'`.

Comment: @user2716941 yeah, changed the answer (included `\d+` to check for the number after `LongUrl`)

Comment: @alecxe make sure you either use a raw string or escape the `\ `. :)

Answer (score 0):

You said: "I'd like to get the content starting with LongUrl and ending with `</a>` or the end of line."

Okay, that would be this regular expression:

```
LongUrl(.*?)(?:</a>|$)
```

This pattern means: "first match the literal string `LongUrl`.  Then start a match group, and inside the match group do a non-greedy pattern that matches anything.  After the match group, start a non-matching group, and inside the non-matching group, match either `</a>` or the end of the line."

I like to add non-matching patterns for white space, so that if spaces ever show up around the text we want, the white space won't be grabbed.  You can easily match 0 or more white space characters with this pattern: `\s*`

Putting it together, here is a working code sample.

```
import re
s_pat = r'LongUrl\s*(.*?)\s*(?:</a>|$)'
pat = re.compile(s_pat)
s0 = "55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async"
s1 = ">55.28 LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async</a></span><br></td>"
m = pat.search(s0)
print(m.group(1))  # prints: 0.20s: Preplan Async
m = pat.search(s1)
print(m.group(1))  # prints: 0.20s: Preplan Async
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string methods:

```
>>> a[a.index("LongUrl"):].partition("</a>")[0]
'LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async'
>>> b[b.index("LongUrl"):].partition("</a>")[0]
'LongUrl0.20s: Preplan Async'
```

Following the comment in another answer (there must be a number after `LongUrl`), you can, for instance, assign the above to `match` and do this:

```
str.isdigit(match[7])
```

But now this method is not as nice.